# Apt not working

Tags: raspbian, ssh, pi-3, apt

When I run `sudo apt-get update` or any other apt command I get this error:

`apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6ld-l)nux-armhf.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How do I fix this?  All help appreciated.

Comment: This exemplifies the original meaning of FUBAR.  By analogy, it is like turning your ignition key, hearing some chugging, then a loud bang followed by copious blue smoke pouring out from under the hood.  The engine is now effectively trashed.  Can it be fixed?  Maybe -- but it may actually cost you less to just buy a whole new engine.  I.e., re-install from scratch.  If you have data you want to salvage, put the card in another computer and access it that way.

Comment: Are use sure the filename is `libc.so.6ld-l)nux-armhf.so.3`? Try running `ldd /usr/bin/apt-get` and check if you have run out of diskspace with `df -h`

Comment: @goldilocks thanks, reinstalled Raspbian. What went wrong?  How will I prevent the problem this time.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't happen; however, it could boil down to filesystem corruption, in which case if it is because of an issue with the card (e.g., it is wearing out) or from having to pull the plug when the system is busy, it is very unlikely to cause the same problem again.  So if you have corruption related issues in the near future, that's probably what went wrong; if you have the exact same problem again, something very strange is going on about which I can't speculate.

Comment: @Sitron_NO I copied and pasted the code so yes that's the filename.